# preventing emacs from newline insertion

Tags: emacs, newline

How can I prevent emacs23 from inserting a newline after

```
C-u M-! date
```

is executed? Setting

```
(setq-default mode-require-final-newline nil)
```

has somehow no effect.

Comment: `C-u M-! date` is essentially using an external utility -- i.e., it is the same as typing date and then the enter key in a regular terminal.  You cannot prevent an external utility from inserting a new line.  You can use Emacs to insert a date and avoid using an external utility; or you can use the external utility and then progammatically delete the new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the newline comes from the 'date' command itself. You need to find a way to make the command omit the final newline, one way to do it would be the following:

```
C-u M-! echo -n "`date`"
```

in which we use that 'echo' allows you to control the final newline. There are of course other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: FWIW you might prefer to use `printf` instead of `echo -n`, as the former is POSIX standard, whereas `echo` can be somewhat inconsistent across different shells.